# Only print Filled Values in an Array C/ get number of filled values In array C

Tags: arrays, c, structure

So i have an array of structures which is created at a fixed size

```
struct student studentArray[32]
```

At some point In my program I have to print the elements of the array, often times before it is full. Now typically If I wanted to the print the elements would do something like this

```
for(int i=0; i< sizeof(studentArray)/sizeof(studentArray[0]); i++){
    printf('structure info here');
}
```

The problem I'm having is that this would Iterate 32 times, since the array size is 32 which I don't wanna do, I would just wanna iterate based on the number of times I've inserted a element into the array. Right now, I am just manually keeping track of number of elements added to array with an integer but I am wondering if there is just a line of code that could get only the number of elements i've inserted and ignore the empty/garbage values of the array.

Comment: There is no such a "line of code" that can do the task instead of you yourself.:)

Comment: The functionality you ask for is available in C++ (using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)), but not in C.

Comment: why not just `struct student_array { int length; struct student students[MAX_SIZE]; }`? An array in C doesn't carry length information - it is just a pointer pointing to somewhere in the memory

Answer (score 1):

There is no special way to tell if a variable is uninitialized.  The best way to handle this is what you're currently doing: keeping track of how many elements are active in a separate variable.